# mixed egg and bicarbonate of soda

Tags: food-safety, cookies

I was half way through making a batch of peanut butter cookies when my mixer blew up - not a happy camper.  As I had already mixed my eggs and bicarbonate of soda together, I would like to know if I can store this mixture in the fridge overnight and resume baking tomorrow?
thank you

Comment: You may lose some rise but might be ok.. only one way to find out. Why can't you finish mixing by hand?

Comment: it is a gluten free product and peanut butter is the base ingredient (1kg), tried but not getting the desired smooth consistency with the sugar and peanut blend (clearly need popeye.  tks for the feedback

Comment: 1kg of peanut butter! That's a lotta cookies! No wonder your mixer gave out lol. Good luck and let us know how you get on with it :)

Comment: LOL Yip and will do

Comment: Gluten free peanut butter cookies with pb as a main base...hmm.  I've made, ah, they're called 1-2-3 peanut butter cookies (1c pb, 1c sugar, 1 egg, optional splash of vanilla or sprinkle cinnamon) which means you might be able to make decent cookies even if the soda doesn't survive.  Or depending on your recipe, this one might be less finicky about mixing.  Hope all turns out well.

Answer (score 2):

Perishable food, including raw eggs, is safe in the fridge for a day. So you can do that.

The soda can spend its leavening power though, especially if you also have other ingredients mixed in. The cookies will not have the same texture as freshly made, and it is hard to say how much difference there will be and where on the spectrum is your limit for "acceptable quality". So, you can go ahead and make them, but be aware that you are facing a significant probability of failure.